# offline ggplot2 documentation?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is not a programming question per se, but seeing as how R and ggplot2 are popular here I thought I'd ask if anyone knows if there is a way to download all of the documentation for ggplot2 at http://docs.ggplot2.org so that they can be accessed offline. I am frequently in a situation where internet access is not available.

Comment: I heard of an alternate technology where they take the accumulated knowledge and compress it into a thing they call a "book".  I don't know if that really has a future, but you could [this one here](http://www.amazon.com/ggplot2-Elegant-Graphics-Data-Analysis/dp/0387981403/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1361733227&sr=8-1&keywords=ggplot2)

Comment: You could try rendering your own version using [staticdocs](https://github.com/hadley/staticdocs) as it appears was done to generate the web pages to which you are referring

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel I'm afraid the ggplot2 book is really quite out of date. It's still good for discussion of the concepts and basic workings, but so much has changed, the online documentation and the book are in no way interchangeable

Comment: provided there's no `robots.txt`, you don't otherwise think you're violating the terms of service, and you have access to `wget`, you could just do a recursive `wget` on the whole site ...

Comment: @BenBolker I don't use wget much - is there a way to tell it a few links to not follow?  The links at the bottom of the page would probably cause a problem if you recursively tried to follow those.

Comment: there are a lot of options, including recursion depth and a domain list include/exclude option ...

Comment: Just out of interest, what is it you're after that's not available from the R-command line `> ?ggplot_[specific_command]`  or the pdf manual available at CRAN?

Comment: The text of the ggplot2 web site is the same as the help files (in fact its automatically generated from the help files using the staticdocs package) so the only real advantage to this is that you get the images too.  If the text is sufficient then you don't need the site.  Anyways, I just tried generating the local docs using staticdocs but got a huge number of errors and it finally stopped before completion so `wget` or other site downloader is probably your best bet.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck What was the error you got?  I was able to run staticdocs just fine.  I'm guessing you didn't have all of the suggested packages installed?

Comment: I have all the packages installed.  I used the latest ggplot2 on CRAN and rebuilt highlight from the CRAN archives since its been orphaned.  Perhaps it only works with the devel version of ggplot2 or if your version of highlight is different perhaps that accounts for it.  I suspect its a version problem.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I just tried it on the version of ggplot2 on CRAN and it worked for me.  I do get a ridiculous number of errors but it doesn't seem to cause problems in terms of the pages being built.  The version of highlight I'm using is the one in my github repo but all I did for that was unpack the archived version and put it in a repo for easy access.

Comment: Did you let it run all the way?  It worked for me until a certain point (except for a huge number of errors which did not seem to prevent it from running) but then it finally it failed. It did manage to create 1223 files by the time it failed.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Yes it worked to completion.  I got a lot of errors as well but nothing that stopped it.  The first time I ran it it stopped fairly quickly because I didn't have all of the packages in ggplot2's SUGGEST field so when it got to those examples it exited.  But it worked fine for me otherwise.  Took a loooonnngg time to run though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about the [R Graphics Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449316956) by Winston Chang?

**Edit:** Or using `wget`, as Ben Bolker suggests:

```
 wget --recursive --no-clobber --page-requisites --html-extension --convert-links   --restrict-file-names=windows --domains=docs.ggplot2.org  http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/
```

The --domains option should prevent to follow links outside of http://docs.ggplot2.org (like those at the bottom of the page). However I did not test that.

Comment: It appears to be the --domain option that is causing troubles for me.  `wget -r -L http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/index.html` works well for me though.

Answer (score 8):

The page itself is created using Hadley's staticdocs package.  You can run staticdocs on ggplot2 yourself to create the pages.  You'll need the `highlight` package to install staticdocs.  You can get that [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/highlight/index.html) or I hosted it on github for my convenience and you could get it with devtools with the commands

```
library(devtools)
install_github("highlight", "Dasonk")
```

to install staticdocs you can use devtools as well

```
install_github("staticdocs")
```

To run staticdocs you'll need the ggplot2 code and it's easiest to grab that with git.  Assuming you're in a directory that you want the ggplot2 folder to be downloaded into you can use the following (assuming you have git installed).

```
git clone https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2.git
```

Alternatively you could grab the package source from the [CRAN page](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/index.html) and unpack that.

Make sure you have the suggested packages for ggplot2 (if you don't then staticdocs will exit abruptly once it hits an example it can't run because you don't have the suggested packages installed).  If you're not sure if you have all the suggested packages it's easiest to just install ggplot2 using the `dependencies=TRUE` paramter.

```
install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)
```

then you can run staticdocs using the following:

```
library(staticdocs)
setwd("path/to/ggplot2/folder")
build_package(".", "inst/staticdocs")
```

Then you can find all the files you need in the inst/staticdocs subfolder and opening index.html will let you browse locally.

Note that using wget or some other method is probably a lot faster and lot easier once you get it to run.  `staticdocs` takes quite a bit of time to run through completion and I didn't browse all the pages to make sure everything turned out alright.  Another disadvantage of this method is that this runs based off the current developmental state of the package and so it might be a little ahead of what you actually have installed on your system.

Answer (score 3):

My response isn't R specific.

When you do have internet, you could manually opens each page and save them. 
For example, if you have Google Chrome (I am sure other browsers have their list of extensions), you can install either Awesome Screenshot: Capture & Annotate or Screen Capture (by Google) from the Chrome Web Store, then choose to capture entire page. There are also extension that lets you save the page as PDF file.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use the `knit_rd()` function in the `knitr` package. This takes the HTML version of the help pages, pulls out the examples, and runs them capturing the output (text or graphical) as `knitr` does. This will give you a directory of HTML files (and graphics) that can be viewed without a connection to the internet. It doesn't look exactly like the website created via `staticdocs`, but it has the same information, including worked examples and the graphical output of those examples.